# How can I describe an incredible release of power, realistically

Tags: magic, explosions

In my writing, a goddess is removed from her position as a god and reduced to a human. ([See my question on writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/51231/how-would-a-god-like-character-react-to-losing-their-godhood/51256#51256)) At the moment of the loss of power huge amounts of energy would be released into the aether, creating a large, magical, overload.

The goddess is a good, loving and caring person, with huge power. She would not allow her power to destroy anything and would not want any "collateral damage."

How can I realistically portray the power leaving a goddess into the aether, and show its magnitude, without it causing damage to the surroundings?

Comment: Is this a worldbuilding or writing problem? If you are not bound by science, you can describe any kind of "silent explosion".

Comment: This has been closed as off-topic, but I'd say that she's a goddess with a determination not to harm innocents (from you post on writing), she'd direct the power *upwards*, away from any that could be harmed. Why not to create a new star in the sky? (Or even a mysterious pale, glowing second moon).

Answer (score 3):

**Matter and power, more specifically a Guardian golem.**

Her power, without intervention, is likely going to manifest itself as different kinds of energy, especially light, heat and in a way, sound (aka a gigantic explosion). Your wonderful goddess however, while still under control of such power, could condensate it in form of matter. Going by Einstein's formula, we can see that small amounts of matter are equivalent to large amounts of energy. Therefore, if your goddess concentrates her power to create matter then she can minimize the effects the same power could cause as an explosion. If she's skilled enough (and as motherly and worried about the evil invasion as you say she is), she could even use such power to create some sort of golem-esque Guardian to assume her position to some degree, so that, despite being now a human, at least she has *someone* left who's loyal to her and won't leave her dear children completely defenseless. Not only that, she could expend a part of her energy making the guardian and depositing the rest of it on him, that way, an incredibly powerful guardian (took so much power to make it, and yet there was so much left its absurdly strong), would be a sudden, yet non destructive way to show why, on a normal basis, one shouldn't mess with Mama god.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey look! Half the moon is gone!**

[image]**

You want a big explosion that doesn't cause any collateral damage? Simple -- take the largest inanimate object you can find and make aim the explosion at that. Traditionally the moon is a good choice. Other good choices include the Sun (which typically results in 3 days of night) and Mt Everest.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that destroying half the moon would have a severe impact on life on earth with subsequent collateral damage.

Comment: You know the moon does have an effect on earth right? Especially regarding tides and slowing the earth's rotation. So blowing half of it might be a problem (what about instead "oh no, pluto is gone"?). Regarding the other options you gave, blowing up a part of the sun might be the best way to cause mass extinction in our planet and an explosion capable of destroying mt Everest will cause severe earthquakes to say the least. So yeah all of these are harmful